# What is the preferred way to set phase-specific environments in Polymer apps?

Tags: polymer

I'm building an web app using Polymer from an app template via `polymer init starter-kit`.

I have some phase-specific environment variable such as backend API entrypoint. There's a behavior for those environment variables:

```
<script>
  EnvBehavior = {
    properties: {
      apiBaseUrl: {
        type: String,
        // value: '//some-url.com'     // production
        value: 'http://localhost:8000' // development
      }
    }
  };
</script>
```

And `apiBaseUrl` is used in other elements:

```
<dom-module id="my-element">
  <template>
    <iron-ajax url="{{apiBaseUrl}}/foo" method="POST" 
           content-type="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" 
           body="{{requestBody}}" handle-as="json" 
           on-response="onResponse" on-error="onError"></iron-ajax>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'my-element',
      properties: {
        requestBody: {foo: 'bar'}
      },
      behaviors: [EnvBehavior],
      onResponse: function(e) {
        console.log(e.detail.response);
      },
      onError: function(e) {
        console.log(e.detail.request.xhr.response);
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

This works. But I'd like to build an app for production with `apiBaseUrl`'s default value `//some-url.com`, which is commented out on the code. How can I effectively set phase-specific variables on build time? I use polymer-cli for build; run `polymer build`.

Comment: I don't think Polymer build has any such feature. You will have to write your own script to take case of that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since it looks like you are already using a separate JS file for implementing the `EnvBehavior`, you could do the following. Create multiple versions of this file, for example:

- `env-behavior.js` (for local),
- `env-behavior.js.stage` (for stage), and
- `env-behavior.js.production` (for production).

Obviously, put appropriate configuration values within each file.

With this, when you will be using `polymer serve` everything should work with the local version (since it is included by default when no file-swapping is done). But when you build for a specific environment, you simply overwrite the `env-behavior.js` with, say, `env-behavior.js.production` when deploying to production.

For swapping files, you can create a manual post-build gulp task or even customize the `polymer build` command by altering the [polymer-build](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-build) code.

Also, I would *strongly advise agains* using client side checks for selecting the appropriate config values, because:

- the code is more complex
- it introduces unnecessary overhead
- everyone can see other config values (e.g. the location of other environments, which can then be targeted by malicious users)
- it looks wrong.

Answer (score 1):

There is no feature that lets you do this with the `polymer-cli`.

Instead of manually changing the `apiBaseUrl` property for development and production you could detect which environment it's running in.

Example:

```
properties: {
    apiBaseUrl: {
        type: String,
        value: function() {
            if (window.location.hostname === 'localhost') {
                return 'http://localhost:8000';
            } else {
                return '//some-url.com';
            }
        }
    }
}
```